# Problemas al pasar valores a un input desde jquery

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Estoy tratando de pasar un valor de php a un input, pero resulta que el input no esta tomando dicho valor, lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#materia').change(function(){
  $.post("./actions/actividades.php", {materia:$('#materia').val()}, function(data){
    $('#actividad').html(data);
   });
 });
 
 $('#curso').change(function(){
  $.post("./actions/estudiantes.php", {curso:$('#curso').val()}, function(data){
    $('#estudiante').html(data);
   });
 });
 
 $('#buscar').click(function(){
  $.post("./actions/consultar_notas.php", {curso: $('#curso').val, materia: $('#materia')}, function(data){
   
  });
 });
 
 $('#curso1').change(function(){
  $.post("actions/buscar_profe.php", {curso: $('#curso1').val()}, function(data){
   $('#profesor').html(data);
  });
  
 });
 
 $('#estudiante').change(function(){
  $('#nombre').value("hola");
  $.get("actions/buscar_estudiante.php", {codigo_estudiante: $('#estudiante').val()}, function(data){
   $('#nombre').val(data.prueba);
  },"json");
 });
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">

                    <label for="curso">Curso</label>
                     <select name="curso" size="1" id="curso" class="selet">
                            <option value="0">Seleccionar curso</option>
                            <?php
                                   $datos = conseguirCursos($db);
                                   if(!empty($datos)):
                                          while($dato = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos)):
                                   ?>
                                                 <option value="<?=$dato['codigo_curso']?>">
                                                        <?=$dato['descripcion']?>
                                                 </option>
                                   <?php
                                          endwhile;
                                   endif;
                            ?>
                     </select>

                     <label for="estudiante" id="notas">Estudiante</label>
                     <select name="estudiante" size="1" id="estudiante" class="selet">
                     </select>
      <?php echo isset($_SESSION['errores']) ? mostrarError($_SESSION['errores'], 'estudiante') : ''; ?>
      
     <div id="datos_estudiante">
      <label for="nombre">Nombres</label>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value=""/>
      <?php echo isset($_SESSION['errores']) ? mostrarError($_SESSION['errores'], 'nombre') : ''; ?>
   <input type="submit" value= "Modificar"/>
              </form>
```

y este es el php que recibe el dato y devuelve el json:

```html
<?php
 $codigo_estudiante = $_GET['codigo_estudiante'];
 echo json_encode(array("prueba"=>$codigo_estudiante));

?>
```

Como pueden ver en esta captura, el json esta retornando el valor:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que estoy haciendo algo mal, pero no he visto el error, agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

Comment: @Riven hola, gracias por tu respuesta, no estoy escribiendo sobre un select si no sobre un input

Comment: Ahhh es que no veo un input con id estudiante en el codigo... pero si debe haber uno... pero no lo veo... seguro lo agregaste?

Comment: @Riven, si, es $('#nombre')

Comment: En teoría yo lo veo bien, que ves si haces un console.log de data ?

lo probé con la consola y funciono bien: var data = {prueba:"1"} $("#nombre").val(data.prueba

Comment: Hola @DarkFrosnight cambie el nombre del input y funciono

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás usando un select para el estudiante. "select" es diferente que el resto de inputs. El formato de un listado de opciones en select, y la forma de obtener los datos de la opción seleccionada es así. Quizás te interese usar un input tipo text, normal y corriente...

nota: aunque no tengas la opción "selected" dentro del option, el jQuery tomará el valor de la opción visible en el campo.

```js
$(function() {
  let val = $("select[name='generos']").children("option:selected").val();
  let desc = $("select[name='generos']").children("option:selected").text();
  
  alert("El valor de la opción es "+ val)
  alert("El texto de la opción es "+ desc)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select name="generos">
<option value="male" selected>Masculino</option>
<option value="female">Femenino</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda